# Using the volume parameters on pyautogui does not work

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

I have a simple program to test pyautogui

```
import pyautogui    

pyautogui.press('numlock')
pyautogui.press('volumemute')
```

The *numlock* toggles correctly, but *volumemute*, *volumedown*, *volumeup* do nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: encountered the same question, using macOS Catalina...